# domain restriction and clear the previously selected value of a many2one field

Tags: dns, odoo

I have two many2one fields (list1 and list2) in the same class and view. I want when a user select a value from list1, the list2 to automatically update with a restriction domain value. this is done

But I also want the 'previously' selected value of list2 to be drop so that the user is force to reselect it, in the case he has previously selected a value in list2 and then reselect in list1. Because domain restriction only update the list2 but leave the previously (now not pertinant) value of list2 and the user can pass. Thx to any help!

this is my code where cours_id is the field name corresponding to list2 in veiw and salle_de_classe_id is the one corresponding to list1:

```
    def on_change_salle_de_classe_id(self,cr,uid,ids,salle_de_classe_id,context=None):
    salle_de_classe = self.pool.get('schoolem.salle_de_classe').browse(cr,uid,salle_de_classe_id)

    cours_obj = self.pool.get('schoolem.cours')
    ids1 = cours_obj.search(cr, uid, [('niveau_id.id', '=', salle_de_classe.classe_id.niveau_id.id)])
    ids2 = cours_obj.search(cr, uid, [('niveau_id.id', '=', salle_de_classe.classe_id.niveau_id.id),('specialite_id.id', '=', salle_de_classe.classe_id.specialite_id.id)])
    #return {'domain':{'cours_id':[('id','in',ids1+ids2)]}}
    return {'domain':{'cours_id':[('id','in',ids1+ids2)]},'value':{'cours_id':False}}
```

This code clear the list2(cours_id field) but i got this error

ProgrammingError: ERREUR:  l'opérateur n'existe pas : integer = boolean
LINE 1: ....id FROM "schoolem_cours" WHERE schoolem_cours.id IN (false)...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Aucun opérateur ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
Vous devez ajouter des conversions explicites de type.

Answer (score 0):

You say the setting a new domain is already done so I presume that you have written an `on_change` method of list1 that returns something like this.

```
{'domain': {'list2': .....
```

To reset the value just add a value...

```
{'domain': ...,
 'value': {'list2': False}}
```

Passing back a value of False will clear the field.

Comment: but got this error:                                          ProgrammingError: ERREUR: l'opérateur n'existe pas : integer = boolean LINE 1: ....id FROM "schoolem_cours" WHERE schoolem_cours.id IN (false)... 
^ HINT: Aucun opérateur ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments. Vous devez ajouter des conversions explicites de type.

Comment: Thank you it works. I have put another on_change action on list2 and it was that which gave me errors. I have fixed it. Please How to return many value for several fields at a time? Thx

Comment: Hey, you just keep stacking as many fields as you want into the value dictionary - res = {'value': {'field1': 1, 'field2':'abc', 'field3': False}}. Note you can also recalculate things like functional fields or readonly fields and pass those back down as well.  The three items you can pass back in a dictionary for an onchange are domain, value and warning (or an empty dictionary).  Cheers, Adrian